# Python, encode strings within a list of lists

Tags: python, list, encode

Am using Python 2.7.

I have a list of lists like:

```
testList2 = [[u'462', u'San Germ\xe1n, PR'],[u'461', u'40341']]
```

I want to encode the strings in the list of lists like:

```
encodedList = [['462', 'San Germ\xc3\xa1n, PR'],['461', '40341']]
```

Tried to write a function to do this (did not work):

```
def testEncode(a):
  for list in a:
    return [x.encode('utf-8') for x in list]
```

I think that for the function to work, it needs to append each encoded list to the prior encoded list to generate an encoded list of lists.  Not sure how to do this.  If someone could explain how the function could be edited to do this, that would be awesome.

I tried the following which did not work either

```
def testEncode(a):
  b = []
  for list in a:
    b.append([x.encode('utf-8') for x in list])
    return b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having realized that your first code is not actually a typographical error but a logical mistake, let me summarize my comments here. There are two problems (both related) in your approaches:

**Problem with the first code**: You are currently returning only the first sublist because you put the return in your for loop. Your input list contains sublists so you need to loop over them in a nested manner. One way is to do it as you are doing in your second approach. Another way is to use list comprehensions. Following is the list comprehension way where `i` will iterate through the sublists and `x` will iterate through the elements of your sublist `i`.

```
def testEncode(a):
    return [[x.encode('utf-8') for x in i] for i in a]
```

**Problem with the second code**: In this attempt of yours, you have basically solved the problem of ignoring the sublists **but** you forgot to put your `return` statement *outside* the for loop. So before your nested for loop iterate through all the sublists, you prematurely return the result. Therefore, you only see the first sublist modified.

```
def testEncode(a):
    b = []
    for list in a:
        b.append([x.encode('utf-8') for x in list])
    return b # <-- Moved outside the for loop now
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the explanation.  The list comprehension feels more concise which appeals to me as a better way